# Access key values from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, automation

In .NET framework i usually store key value pipeline variables in a app.config file and access those key values by doing the following

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseURL" value=""/>
    <add key="Env" value=""/>
    <add key="API_KEY" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

```
 public static class PipelineVariables
    {
        public static string BaseURL => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
        public static string Environment => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Env"];
        public static string APIKEY => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_KEY"];
    }
```

Just for fun i want to do a API test automation project using Visual Studio Code and .Net Core

I created the following appsettings.json

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
          "BaseURL": "",
          "Env": "",
          "API_KEY": ""
      }
  }
```

Just wondering whats the recommended way to access these key values? I will use these values as pipeline variables in which i will store in Azure. I want to access the key values to pass into my code.

***UPDATE: I got it working similar to the way i do it in .NET Framework projects

I would like the be able to use switch statement on these variables for use in Azure for CI/CD, hence why i want separate methods for variable

However if the a way to simplify the below code?

```
      public static string APIKey =>  new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName)
                                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true).Build().GetSection("AppSettings:API_KEY")?.Value;

        public static string BaseURL =>  new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName)
                                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true).Build().GetSection("AppSettings:BaseURL")?.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which type application you run. You can solve it in a multiple way.

For example in Dotnet Core API in the startup class (This is often already auto generated in a API or MVC project):

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string apiKey = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:API_KEY")?.Value;
}
```

But you can for example run it also in an console application or different kind project:

```
public void Load()
{
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Path.Combine("baseDirectory"))
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
   .AddEnvironmentVariables();

   var config = builder.Build();
   string apiKey = config["AppSettings:API_KEY"];
}
```

Add the following nuget packages to make the code from above work:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

***UPDATE: Maybe this helps you to simplfy the code:

```
public class PipelineVariables
{
    public string BaseURL { get; set; }
    public string Environment { get; set; }
    public string APIKEY { get; set; }

    private static PipelineVariables pipelineVariables;

    public static PipelineVariables Get()
    {
        if (pipelineVariables == null)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine("baseDirectory"))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var config = builder.Build();

            pipelineVariables = new PipelineVariables
            {
                APIKEY = config["AppSettings:API_KEY"],
                BaseURL = config["AppSettings:BaseURL"],
                Environment = config["AppSettings:Env"]
            };
        }

        return pipelineVariables;
    }
}
```

Or a more direct solution is get the config class this way:

```
    pipelineVariables = config.GetSection(nameof(PipelineVariables)).Get<PipelineVariables>();
```

Only the names of variables in the class needs to be same as in the appsettings.json

The appsettings.json will became this way:

```
{
    "PipelineVariables": {
          "BaseURL": "",
          "Environment": "",
          "APIKEY": ""
      }
}
```

Or you just change the properties and the class name in C#.

Example to get the settings:

```
public void RunPipeline() 
{
     PipelineVariables variables = PipelineVariables.Get();
     Console.WriteLine(variables.BaseURL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful in me trying to solve this. I added an update the my original post to see if i can simplify my current solution

Comment: @IOF I just updated my answer. Maybe it helps you to simplify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

in asp .net core api you can use this solution :

1.Create your base  AppSettings class with your properties :

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string BaseURL { get; set; }
    public string Env { get; set; }
    public string API_KEY { get; set; }
}
```

2.You get your section from appsettingjson in startup ctor :

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
  .AddEnvironmentVariables();
  this.Configuration = builder.Build();
  var settings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)).Get<AppSettings>();
```

3.Now you get your settings from appsettingjson in "settings" instance and you can use it in your statics feild